# Comparing unsigned char to a negative number

Tags: c

I was wondering what happens in line 9 in ar[i] != -1. The result is that the loop doesn't stop, but I'm not sure why.

```
  4 int main()
  5 {
  6     unsigned char ar[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1};
  7     int i;
  8
  9     for (i = 0; ar[i] != -1; i++)
 10     {
 11         printf("ar: %u\n", ar[i] );
 12     }
 13     printf("out: %u\n", ar[i] );
 14
 15     return 0;
 16
 17 }
```

Thanks,

Comment: What are the values of `UCHAR_MAX` and `INT_MAX`?

Comment: If you're using GCC and have enabled warnings, it should warn you about signed vs unsigned comparisons. In any case, unsigned numbers cannot store negative numbers.

Comment: `unsigned char` is unsigned, and thus never equals `-1`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen If `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, the comparison will be done as `unsigned`. If `UCHAR_MAX == UINT_MAX`, the value of `-1` will compare equal.

Comment: @EOF Alright, to be more precise: *`unsigned char` is unsigned, and thus can equal `-1` if and only if `sizeof(int) == 1`*. Although people working on such systems and relying on that behavior should already know that, so the comment was not really addressed to them. But yeah, the first comment was technically wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`unsigned char ar[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1};` initializes `ar[5]` to `(unsigned char)-1`, which is `255` because unsigned arithmetic works by wrapping around.

Then you do `ar[5] != -1`. The *integer promotions* take the left-hand-side from `unsigned char` to `int` without changing the value. This makes the comparison `255 != -1`, which is true and so the loop continues.

One solution would be for the loop condition to test against `(unsigned char)-1`. Alternatively you could use the array dimension instead of a sentinel value.

Comment: and then what happens? when comparing a char and an integer, (0xff != 0xffffffff), what does the compiler do? how does it compare it? One can also guess the compiler will pad the 0xff with 'f' and then the comparison would be 0xffffffff != 0xffffffff which is false (they are equal)

Comment: There is no `0xffffffff` involved. There are ints `255` and `-1`. Those are different `int` values. C arithmetic works in terms of values. The representation in memory doesn't matter

Comment: @nerez Give one good reason why the compiler should do such cast `0xff`->`0xffffffff`? First examine with `gdb` or simple examples e.g.: `char ch = 'A'; int a = ch; printf("%x",a)` then write such comments

Comment: This answer is all good, only one simple thing is missing, the origin of all this trouble, namely that one should never use variables of a type that is narrower than `int`  for arithmetic or comparison. `char` is for strings and `[un]signed char` are for very special purposes, none of which applies here.

Comment: @M.M.: I see...I will try the second thing(reading answers) then and try to answer accordingly. BTW when I asked you to go other irc chat..you felt offended? I am sorry if it sounded bad. But actually there it is a lot easier to talk and yes editing and all that are easy too. You can delete comments too...you helped me a lot. Thanks